# SQL View: ORA Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, view, peoplesoft

I created a view in MS SQL. It worked perfectly. When I exported and imported my project into an Oracle environment, the view didn't work anymore. As far as I know, I used META SQL.

Hope someone can help!

```
SELECT OPRID 
 , DESCR1 
 , DESCR 
 , DESCR5 
 , DESCR6 
 , DESCR7 
 , YEAR 
 , WEEKOFYEAR 
 --When working more then 6 hours, subtract .5 hours break
 , CASE WHEN (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1) 
 , DATEDIFF(MINUTE 
 , DG_MONDAY_START 
 , DG_MONDAY_END))/60) >= 6 THEN (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1) 
 , DATEDIFF(MINUTE 
 , DG_MONDAY_START 
 , DG_MONDAY_END))/60 - 0.5) ELSE (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1) 
 , DATEDIFF(MINUTE 
 , DG_MONDAY_START 
 , DG_MONDAY_END))/60) END AS 'MONDAY' 
 , CASE WHEN (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1) 
 , DATEDIFF(MINUTE 
 , DG_TUESDAY_START 
 , DG_TUESDAY_END))/60) >= 6 THEN (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1) 
 , DATEDIFF(MINUTE 
 , DG_TUESDAY_START 
 , DG_TUESDAY_END))/60 - 0.5) ELSE (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1) 
 , DATEDIFF(MINUTE 
 , DG_TUESDAY_START 
 , DG_TUESDAY_END))/60) END AS 'TUESDAY' 
 , CASE WHEN (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1) 
 , DATEDIFF(MINUTE 
 , DG_WEDNESDAY_START 
 , DG_WEDNESDAY_END))/60) >= 6 THEN (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1) 
 , DATEDIFF(MINUTE 
 , DG_WEDNESDAY_START 
 , DG_WEDNESDAY_END))/60 - 0.5) ELSE (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1) 
 , DATEDIFF(MINUTE 
 , DG_WEDNESDAY_START 
 , DG_WEDNESDAY_END))/60) END AS 'WEDNESDAY' 
 , CASE WHEN (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1) 
 , DATEDIFF(MINUTE 
 , DG_THURSDAY_START 
 , DG_THURSDAY_END))/60) >= 6 THEN (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1) 
 , DATEDIFF(MINUTE 
 , DG_THURSDAY_START 
 , DG_THURSDAY_END))/60 - 0.5) ELSE (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1) 
 , DATEDIFF(MINUTE 
 , DG_THURSDAY_START 
 , DG_THURSDAY_END))/60) END AS 'THURSDAY' 
 , CASE WHEN(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1) 
 , DATEDIFF(MINUTE 
 , DG_FRIDAY_START 
 , DG_FRIDAY_END))/60) >= 6 THEN (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1) 
 , DATEDIFF(MINUTE 
 , DG_FRIDAY_START 
 , DG_FRIDAY_END))/60 - 0.5) ELSE (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1) 
 , DATEDIFF(MINUTE 
 , DG_FRIDAY_START 
 , DG_FRIDAY_END))/60) END AS 'FRIDAY' 
 , '0' AS 'TOTAL' 
 --Total will be calculated in PeopleCode
  FROM PS_DG_BPV_ROSTER 
 WHERE YEAR LIKE YEAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD')) 
   AND (DG_MONDAY_START != DG_MONDAY_END 
    OR DG_TUESDAY_START != DG_TUESDAY_END 
    OR DG_WEDNESDAY_START != DG_WEDNESDAY_END 
    OR DG_THURSDAY_START != DG_THURSDAY_END 
    OR DG_FRIDAY_START != DG_FRIDAY_END)
```

Comment: In ORACLE doesn't exist command CONVERT, change with CAST

Comment: Also, the case statement should be `CASE MONDAY WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END, CASE TUESDAY WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END`

Comment: @Laurens no you don't, you have `CASE ... END AS MONDAY`

Comment: Ah that way.. Thanks! Doesn't totally solve the problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query, you use `CONVERT` command but in Oracle you must use `CAST`.

The type DECIMAL must be changed with NUMBER type as follow.

Instead of:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1), field)
```

Use:

```
CAST(field as NUMBER(10,1))
```

Tell me if it's OK

**EDIT** After comment

In Oracle the Sql Server function DATEDIFF has been replaced with `-` sign, as a normal difference between two DATA field.

I advice you this [site](http://psoug.org/reference/sqlserver.html) where you'll find the equivalent function between Oracle 10g and Sql Server 2008R2

Comment: When I try to run it,oracle throws me an SQL Error: ORA-00904: "DATEDIFF": ongeldige ID
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: In Oracle DATEDIFF can be replaced with sign - as difference between DATA field

Comment: And how does it come back? Seconds? Milliseconds?

Comment: you must convert your date difference in minute apply *24 * 60 (and so on). Show here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206222/oracle-best-select-statement-for-getting-the-difference-in-minutes-between-two