# How to write a query to fetch data from exactly 25 mins back to 15 mins back? Oracle sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a query like below;

```
SELECT fielda,fieldb,fieldc  
from mytable 
where timefield between to_date((to_char(sysdate-1/24, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24') || ':00:00'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
                    and to_date((to_char(sysdate-1/24, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24') || ':59:59'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

This query takes value from the `0`th and `59`th minute of hour before previous hour. What I want is, I want to run a query, which runs on 10th minute. The query should fetch rows from my table, where time is between 25 minures and 15 minutes related to the current. For example, I run the query in 09:10:00 and some seconds. It should fetch rows where timefield is between 08:50 and 08:59:00 (i want to include data in 8:50 and 8:59). How can I do this?

Comment: This answer should give u a good insight on how to do it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206222/oracle-best-select-statement-for-getting-the-difference-in-minutes-between-two

Comment: Do you mean between 08:50 and 08:59:59? If not, where does the data from the last minute go? (From 08:59 to 08:59:59)

Comment: **AND**: If you run at 09:10 and you want between 25 and 15 minutes prior, how is that from 8:50 to 8:59 anyway? Do you mean 8:45 to 8:55?

Answer (score 2):

You'd truncate `SYSDATE` to the minute and subtract the desired interval. Use `>=` and `<` in order to deal with seconds and fractions thereof properly.

```
select fielda, fieldb, fieldc
from mytable 
where timefield >= trunc(sysdate, 'minute') - interval '25' minute
  and timefield <  trunc(sysdate, 'minute') - interval '20' minute;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable 
WHERE timefield >= sysdate - (25/1440)
  AND timefield <= sysdate - (10/1440)
```

> 24*60 = 1440

Comment: It is not entirely clear, but it seems (from the narrative) the OP also wants to truncate the range endpoints to the nearest minute.

Comment: @mathguy Maybe you are right, but I dont see that :/ especially because the `9:59:59`

Comment: Sorry; "narrative" means the explanation in words. The OP says : *For example, I run the query in 09:10:00* **and some seconds.** *It should fetch rows where timefield is between 08:50 and 08:59:00* (In a comment I pointed out that 08:59:00 is probably wrong, should be 08:59:59).

Comment: @mathguy Yes, I up vote the comment, but the narrative doesn't match the title or the 10 minutes interval. In that case is only 9 minutes

Comment: lol - yes, and the wrong interval too (as I just pointed out in a second comment). As usual, there is no point in the solution being more precise than the problem!

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.