# time difference between current timestamp and specific time in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to know how to get time difference in minutes between systimestamp and start_time as below.And the start_time datatype is date.
kindly help me.Give answers which is applicable for oracle.

```
start_time                 systimestamp     runningtime(systimestmap-start_time)
7/6/2017 9:34:54 AM        17:06:08         time difference in minutes
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle - Best SELECT statement for getting the difference in minutes between two DateTime columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206222/oracle-best-select-statement-for-getting-the-difference-in-minutes-between-two)

Comment: @Take_Care_ - When you point out a duplicate, why don't you also vote to close at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `sysdate` instead, you can take the difference and do some arithmetic:

```
select trunc((sysdate - start_time) * 24 * 60)
```